# ASP.net MVC Web Api + Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, json

What is the best method for accessing MVC Web API in an Android Application? `JSONParser` or `HttpResponse` ?

Please advise !!!

Thanks.

Comment: Json is very common format, MVC and android both have much better support for better. You can use JSON better then plain response.

Comment: would it have to host my WEBAPI project on Local ISS in order to access it in andoird Applicatin ? 

 I followed that tutorial to create my own application .

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html

Comment: If you testing in emulator then you can use ISS express in your system (come within VS) or use Windows Azure 30 days trial for test it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if you are asking how to use an *existing* web API or how you should design a *new* web API.

If the MVC Web API exists and returns JSON, use a JSON parser. Otherwise, if it just returns XML, you should just parse the XML the API using the java XML parsing libraries. [Here's an example of how to do that](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) (though, in your case, instead of parsing a File, you would parse the web service response)

If you are asking how to design a new web API, I would go with returning JSON from the Web API  and parsing the JSON in android using some Java JSON parsing library (there are a lot).

Comment: actually i design a Simple MVC Webapi which return JSON , now i want to access it in my android application , i used JSONParser for this , my JSONParser returns url of my WEBAPI Address , but enable to fetech data ..
I follow this example to use my webpi through jsonparser

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html